# Print half of A4 PDF on A5 paper

Tags: windows, pdf, printing

One of our programs generates special labels on an A4 pdf but these are always only half of the A4.
Currently we print them on A4 and then have to manually cut the pages in 2 which is a pretty time consuming process and a huge waste of paper.

Is there a easy way so the text part gets printed on A5 instead?

Below an example of the current labels.

> [image: Example of the type of pages]

Since we have to print around 100 of these labels every day, an automated process would be preferred.

EDIT
Following the advice given in the comments I have contacted our supplier of the software and turned out it was an easy customization to change the generated pdf's to A5 format.
thanks for the help.
(Should I delete this question now?)

Comment: Can't the program generating labels be configured to different size of paper? Any other solution will be bad, honestly.

Comment: Sadly we have no control over how the labels are generated.

Comment: Maybe it's taking into account the bottom margin of your printer. If it prints in roughly half of an A4 (portrait), the bottom margin being irrelevant,  theoretically it could do it in an A5 (landscape) but then the bottom margin would be the right side of the labels and potentially cut off.

Comment: You could use a program like image magick to do the job...

Comment: Many PDF viewers (and other editors) have a setting for printing **multiple PDF pages** on a single page of paper. If your program doesn't, then try free PDF-XChange or fee Sumatra.

Comment: I assume you are using Windows (XP, 7, 8, 10). In what file-format are the labels created? Can you print it to PDF first? Did you try adding the same printer again and setting it to A5 only? Why not use a label printer like Toshiba B-FV4T? What printer are you even using? Normal office, professional office or an actual label printer? If you can tell us, what program are you using? If it's a company made program, you don't have to tell us of course, but the programming language would be good to know.

Comment: @VarmintLP I have no idea in what format the labels are generated inside the program. We can export them to multiple formats or just print them directly. The program isn't made by us, it's a bought ERP system that generates these labels. We use a professional office printer.

Comment: @ThomasS ok, if you had an actual label printer you could exported the labels as PDF and specify it's A5. That might leave out the excessive white part. I take it the labels are for shipping or to label products, right? If it's the later, the content probably never changes and it would be better to consider using PDF files from the beginning.